# Processing one column text by index to several new columns based on specific word in text

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a problem with pandas code and after trying to search for an answer for hours and hours I finally gave up and came here for help!

My dataframe, which is created from larger excel file, consist of specific observations that are at the same time defined as the index. Now I have one column where these observations have provided text answers, and most of these observations have provided several responses. Here is an example of my output.

```
Org        Data1
 x          aaa
 x          aaa
 x          bbb
 y          aaa
 z          ccc
 z          ddd
 z          ddd
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
 Org    One    Two    Three   Four
  x      1      1      0       0
  y      1      0      0       0
  z      0      0      1       1

 Data1 column is deleted and new columns correspond text answers like this: 
 "One" = aaa, "Two" = bbb, "Three" = ccc, and "Four" = ddd.
```

The idea is to group everything together by the index "Org", and create new columns based on the "Data1" columns answers. So in example as the "Org" x has responded in "Data1" to aaa twice and bbb once, the code would create a new column "One" and "Two" and with true or false function place either 1 or 0 to this new column. The idea is also to ignore responses that have been given more than once, but I guess with true or false function this is not an issue and there is no need to drop duplicates (?). Note that the answers are not in any specific order and in total I have about 10000 rows, I use loc to select specific "Org":s already, which I am interested in.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
df = pd.read_excel("location\test.xlsx", sheetname="Sheet1", 
index_col="Org").loc[["x", "y", "z"], ["Data1"]]

df["One"] = np.where(df["Data1"].str.contains["aaa"], "1", "0")
```

By also doing df["Two"], df["Three"] etc. and finally deleting the Data1 column, and processing the results further by using groupby and sum I am able to get to my final result. However then I have columns with "2" or "3" instead of the "1", which I am looking for. Obviously this is not a huge task to process further but I have been trying to come up with a better solution than groupby and sum, since it would be beneficial in the future of dealing with this excel file.

What I have tried are the following:

```
1
df = pd.read_excel("location\test.xlsx", sheetname="Sheet1", 
index_col="Org").loc[["x", "y", "z"], ["Data1"]].groupby("Org").agg(lambda
x: set (x))

2
df = pd.read_excel("location\test.xlsx", sheetname="Sheet1", 
index_col="Org").loc[["x", "y", "z"], ["Data1"]].groupby(["Org"])
["Data1"].agg(lambda x: ";;".join(set(x.astype(str)))).str.split(";;")
```

The first solution works fine as it groups the same index "Org" answers to one row from previous several rows. However when applying the np.where and str.contains I receive i.e. new column "One" where every observation "Org" has "1", which is wrong. The second solution does not function properly because it looses the original column name which is needed until each possible "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" answer have been processed, and I am not able to look for "aaa" with np.where and str.contains.

Is anyone able to help me with this "tricky" problem, since I am still learning pandas. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do it is using `pivot_table` from Pandas:

```
df['num_val']=1
df=df.pivot_table(values='num_val', columns='Data1', index='Org', fill_value=0)
df.columns=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
```

Comment: optionally add reset_index to the last line to get the exact form you want (org as a column not index)

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked almost perfectly. Somehow this code is missing the index "Org" observations that have not responded anything so I am missing rows. I tried adding dropna=False after fill_value=0 but it did not work. Any idea how to involve also such observations that have not responded anything?

Comment: @hexi: look at my answer below

Comment: Got this working then using fillna("NAN", inplace=True) and then applying the method. Finally I just delete the NAN column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by pivoting the table and then applying the condition:

```
df1=pd.pivot_table(df,index='Org', values=['Org'], columns=['Data1'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).fillna(0).reset_index()
df1.index.name=None 
df1.columns = ["Org","One","Two","Three","Four"]
df1.set_index('Org', inplace=True)
df1.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x>=1 else 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help as well. There seems to be key error with "Org" within the first line, but I could not yet discover why because everything seems to be okay, at least from beginners perspective. I am trying to look for errors in the code I entered.

Comment: I used your first output with Org and Data1 as a csv

Comment: Is there a difference because my original data where the dataframe is constructed comes from xlsx?

Comment: You already index it with Org. So in my code snippet, remove set_index and you should be good.Check the columns  as well. Just to be sure,  share your dataframe after you read from excel.

Comment: I'm still working on it, the issue is within the first line and I keep receiving KeyError "Org". Can this come from the reason that while reading in the excel I already set the index_col "Org"?

Comment: Yes, after the index is set, it is no longer a column. So, when we try to set_index, it won't find it and throw a key error

Comment: Allright, I need to set the index column when reading the excel file in order to locate (loc) the certain "Org":s what I am processing. However, the key error comes in df1=pd.pivot_table(df,index="Org", values=["Org]... I am trying to understand how to modify this but I have not yet come up with a solution. By the way, Thank you very much for helping me with this issue! I think that your solution will eventually be better (as soon as I get it to work) since the first solution does not involve "Org":s whom have not answered anything.

Comment: @hexi Great. Will appreciate if you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: I managed to get the first solution to work by fillna=("NAN" inplace=True) and after that using the provided code. I just delete the created NAN column in the end. This seemed more easier than your solution in the end.